# Mixing Multiple Programs

Tags: mixing, program-structure

My question is about mixing multiple programs. For example if you use Unreal Development Kit before you know what I'm talking about. The Lightmass of Unreal is another program which have another exe from the main application (editor). When you build the lighting, lightmass program  will run in the background. How it is working? Has the main program give a memory location to Lightmass? or are they communucating via windows messages/sockets.or something.

Btw. Maybe a related maybe not I don't sure, What is the argument parameters of C/C++ main function. What is its purpose exactly and where it can be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some search and now I know that I meant IPC (Inter Process Communucation)